# Accessing a USB device on a specific port on a tablet programatically without using the drive letter in Windows 8 (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usb, tablet

I am developing an application which will be deployed on a specific Windows 8 tablet with a fixed number of USB ports and I want to ensure that only one of those ports is actually used for external storage.

The application needs to read/write data to the external device but only if it is that particular USB port.

The solution should be generic so that all tablets of this particular model will work (so I guess hard coding addresses will not work).

I cannot use the drive letter to distinguish between USB ports because they are not static and not necessarily allocated the same letters consistently. I also wish to make this solution as transparent to the user as possible.

Comment: You can use [`mountvol`](http://superuser.com/questions/465730/access-to-a-disk-drive-using-volume-id-instead-of-a-drive-letter-in-windows) to get a list of GUIDs and then simply access the drive with those.

Comment: I need a solution in C++. Mountvol will also not work for this problem because I still need to identify the correct USB port...

Comment: ... e.g. I cannot guarantee that drive letter A:\ is associated with USB Port 0.

Comment: This question makes little sense.  The B in USB means Bus.  It is Universal.  The user can plug in a device in any port, just as you can plug in a card in any slot inside a desktop machine.  There is *always* a device driver involved that is capable of detecting the actual device that got plugged in, being able to distinguish between a coffee-cup warmer, a memory stick, a WiFi adapter, etcetera.  You only ever work with the driver, you never address the bus yourself.  And most definitely never care what port the user used.

Comment: We need the usb ports to be dedicated, so for example port 0 on the device is only meant to be used for bluetooth, port 1 should only be used for external drive etc. this is because of the way the ports are positioned and how the tablet will be used in the field. In addition we do not want the user to have to identify/select the USB drive (by it's letter) in the application.

Comment: So instead of making the user select the USB drive letter, you're going to make him remember which port he needs to plug specific devices into? Maybe a better solution would be for your application to automatically recognize which device is plugged in which port, perhaps from device name strings reported by the device driver.